# Check if option is selected

Tags: jquery

I am making a file for my company on their CMS using HTML, CSS, PHP and jQuery,
I made a `select` with several `option` elements as return reasons.
Some content is hidden and `show()` is only run when an certain option is selected.

jQuery code:

```
// if option defective product is selected, vehicle information gets showed

$("select#ReasonReturn").change(function() {
  var data = $("select#ReasonReturn option:selected").val();
  if ($(this).val() === 'Defectiveproduct') {
    $("td[data-block=vehicle-information]").show();
    $("td[remark-block=remark-header]").text('Toelichting');
  }

});


// if option other is selected remark changes to other, namely / remark

$("select#ReasonReturn").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'Other') {
    $("td[remark-block=remark-header]").text('Anders, namelijk / Toelichting');
    $("td[data-block=vehicle-information]").hide();
  }

});

//if any other option is selected set to default

$("select#ReasonReturn").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != 'Other' && $(this).val() != 'Defectiveproduct') {
    $("td[remark-block=remark-header]").text('Toelichting');
    $("td[data-block=vehicle-information]").hide();
  }
});
```

As you can see I'am currently using the `change()` event to detect a change. 
The only problem with this is that when I reload the page the "Defective Product" option is still selected. Nothing happens because the event will only get triggered on change and not on select.

My question is:

Is there an easy way to check the selected value directly after the page loads instead only on change?
I hope my question is clear, thanks for the help!

PS: I can show more code if necessary.

Comment: you could add another line that checks upon `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to register multiple `change` handlers, you can do it with only one change event handler by using `if () {} else if(){}` statement.

Second, put your all code inside of DOM ready function and call the change event to do your job when the DOM is ready.

```
  $(function(){

    $("select#ReasonReturn").change(function() {
      var data = $("select#ReasonReturn option:selected").val();

      if ($(this).val() === 'Defectiveproduct'){
        $("td[data-block=vehicle-information]").show();
        $("td[remark-block=remark-header]").text('Toelichting');
      }else if($(this).val() === 'Other') { 
        // if option other is selected remark changes to other, namely / remark
        $("td[remark-block=remark-header]").text('Anders, namelijk / Toelichting');
        $("td[data-block=vehicle-information]").hide();
      }else if ($(this).val() != 'Other' && $(this).val() != 'Defectiveproduct') {

        //if any other option is selected set to default
        $("td[remark-block=remark-header]").text('Toelichting');
        $("td[data-block=vehicle-information]").hide();
      }
    }).change();

  });
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share this method, i adjusted my code and everything works as it should be. This looks much more clear and efficient. I accepted your answer, have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

this should do the work for you on page reload

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("select#ReasonReturn").trigger('change');
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check selected value on page load. Please try with following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select#ReasonReturn option:selected").val();
});
```